# Как улучшить предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Есть предложение (это описание города):

*Поэтому **есть** там и один типичный супермаркет, и высотная застройка, где  **размещаются в основном** разнообразные учреждения.*

Есть программа Главред https://glvrd.ru/

Она сообщила, что при проверке чистоты предложения обнаружено: 3 стоп-слова (они подчеркнуты). Основные проблемы: слабый глагол, необъективная оценка, неопределенность, газетный штамп.

Конечно, эта программа для  текстов с художественным уклоном не рекомендуется, но проверить всё рано не мешает. Так где здесь слабый глагол, газетный штамп и как бы от них избавиться?

Comment: У меня не выбивает "газетный штамп". Проверьте ещё раз. Он точно есть?

Comment: Завтра проверю, поздно уже. Лучше предложение поправили бы. Мне кажется, что "размещаются учреждения" надо бы заменить. А слабый глагол где? Размещаются?

Comment: (Так проверять 10 секунд.) Нет, "есть", при замене на "расположен" он исчезает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Так где здесь слабый глагол, газетный штамп и как бы от них избавиться?

Если стать курсором мыши на выделенное слово, то в колонке справа будет показано подробное объяснение по этому слову, а также рекомендации по исправлению и пример.

Слабый глагол здесь **есть**, но я не думаю, что с ним нужно бороться.

Неопределённость — **различные** и необъективность — **в основном**. Последнее легко побороть, заменив "в основном" на **преимущественно** (не уверен, что в этой замене есть смысл, хотя мне само слово нравится больше). А что делать с "различными учреждениями" я не знаю, поскольку неопределённость слишком велика, и это плохо даже для художественного текста. Но чтобы исправить, нужно понимать какие учреждения имеется в виду. Это офисы коммерческих организаций, муниципальные учреждения, больницы, библиотеки, вузы, музеи, др.?

Мой вариант примерной правки:

> Поэтому есть там и типичный супермаркет, и высотная застройка,
>   в которой размещаются преимущественно муниципальные учреждения.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, В Вашем варианте за предложение ставят 9 баллов (почти максимум). У программы "аллергия" на любую неопределенность и низкую информативность.  Правда, разница между "преимущественно" и  "в основном" не очень ясная, как и стиль тоже. Об этом надо подумать. Но в общем программа может быть полезной при работе, если в их вариант текста вносить поправку на "художественность".

Answer (score 1):

Неопределённость можно увидеть в абстрактном выражении "*высотная застройка*" (обычно это *принцип* застройки территории), которое не сочетается как элемент перечисления со вполне конкретным "супермаркетом": это трудно представимое сочетание, примерно такое, как "(на тарелке лежал) *кусок хлеба и сдобная выпечка*". Желательно как минимум конкретизирующее слово добавить: "есть там и *район* (область) *высотной застройки*". Или можно говорить е о "застройке", а о "постройках", "зданиях" - это и от *штампов* уведёт,  ведь никто не называет "высотной застройкой" напр. часто показываемые шанхайские небоскрёбы с телебашней в районе Пудун.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за ваше мнение, но мне сочетание "высотная застройка" в принципе нравится. В нем в данном случае нет терминологии, но есть нечто разговорное, немного ироничное. Как, например, у Аксенова: Саша Корбах приник к окну. Этот-то вот массив, сплошная высотная застройка, скопление кухонь, мусоропроводов, всяких шторок, шатких сидений, холодильников «Север» и телевизоров «Рубин»...  [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (1997)]